# jQuery - i cant see any error

Tags: jquery

I must select right options in some `<select>` tags. I have an array where the key is the number of tags and the value is the value attribute of option which i must select.

**Here is my code:**

```
//array ids contains values of option to select.
//.ingredients is class of <select> tags

var i=0;

$('.ingredients').each(function() {

$(this).find('option[value="' + ids[i] + '"]').attr("selected","selected");
i++                  
});
```

For each option of `<select class='ingredients>` select right option field. Key of ids array means number of `<select>` tag. This is what i want to do.

Can anyone tell me what the error is?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a ";" after the `i++` ...

You could use `index` with `each()` instead of using the "i" variable:

```
$('.ingredients').each(function(index) {
  $(this).find('option[value="' + ids[index] + '"]').attr("selected","selected");
});
```

Also, Setting the selected attr on an option is a bit trickier than what you might think at first because it effects other elements if the select element is of type 'select-one'.  Here's a little plugin provided within the jQuery Form plugin that handles selecting/deselecting options as well as checkboxes and radios.  Use it like this:

Just put this somewhere in your code :

```
$.fn.selected = function(select) {
    if (select == undefined) select = true;
    return this.each(function() {
        var t = this.type;
        if (t == 'checkbox' || t == 'radio')
            this.checked = select;
        else if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'option') {
            var $sel = $(this).parent('select');
            if (select && $sel[0] && $sel[0].type == 'select-one') {
                // deselect all other options
                $sel.find('option').selected(false);
            }
            this.selected = select;
        }
    });
};
```

Then try to replace the code you gave first by this :

```
$('.ingredients').each(function(index) {
  $(this).find('option[value="' + ids[index] + '"]').selected(true);
});
```

Comment: it doesnt work, i dont know where is the problem.. It doesnt select any option

Comment: can you help me? here is full code (about 95 line) [link](http://soap.protein24.co.uk/datasheets/)

Comment: it also doesnt work.. i dont understand it. if i add "new value"  and then add new igredient it must reload select fields with new ingredient and save selected value. i have no idea whats wrong

Comment: Sorry but the problem can be anywhere, try to find out why it won't update (do some simple test to see where it doesn't work, ALWAYS selecting the option number one ...)
Use the plugin i gave you, it'll work better !
Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.attr("selected", "selected")`, try `.prop("selected", true)`

[Update]

Actually, I don't see any problem with the code. It is working. I think the problem is with your HTML. Are you executing the code before DOM Ready event?

See http://jsfiddle.net/VPcMx/

Try

```
 $(function(){
    $('.ingredients').each(function(i) {

        $(this).find('option[value="' + ids[i] + '"]').prop("selected", true);
        i++                  
    });
});
```

Comment: here is full code - can you help me? [link](http://soap.protein24.co.uk/datasheets/)   (about 95 line)